# How to include our own mfile into matlab library?

Tags: matlab

I have created my own mfile and would like to add it permanently lie built in functions so that I dont have to specify path. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your `.m` file (either `script` or `function`) in a folder belonging to the MatLab `search path`.

To add your own folder to the MatLab `search path` you can use eiterh:

- the `Set Path` tool, available on the MatLab `Home toolbar`
- use the buil-in function `path` (from the `Command Window` or, for example, as part of a script)

E. g.

```
path(path,'c:\my_folder\my_sub_folder')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write your file and save it and then add the containing folder to the MATLAB search path. You do not need to look for it every time.

```
addpath('c:/matlab/myfiles')
```

**Note:** your filename should not exist within MATLAB, otherwise your file would be the default one, when you call that command.

---

You can also do most of the work from command-line:
First, create a folder,

```
mkdir('c:/matlab/myfiles')
```

Add it to the top of your search path,

```
addpath('c:/matlab/myfiles')
```

and then save the search path for future MATLAB sessions

```
savepath c:/matlab/myfiles/pathdef.m
```